# Can you save both Highpool and the AG Center

Tags: wasteland-2

It looks like the plot is designed so one of the town will fall, is there a hidden secret so you can you save both Highpool and the AG Center ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can only save one or the other; it's about making a tough decision and the consequences of it. But [there seems to be a way to let both get destroyed/overrun](https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com/viewtopic.php?f=40&t=9144#p123064).

Answer (score 0):

Nope.  You can't even visit both of their outer areas in their un-ruined state; if you leave one, the other skips any steps left in its destruction process and goes straight to wrecked.