# What happens to Highpool if you save Ag Center first?

Tags: wasteland-2

My squad had just dealt with Highpool, and when Kate briefed me on the matters I realized that a desert with lots of oasis probably needs less mutant plants more than a small dam. The radio transmission says that Highpool is expecting Skorpion backup, do they actually appear in Highpool if I choose Ag Center instead?

Comment: Yes, Highpool will be destoryed by raiders if you go Ag Center. I think you can't save both side.

Comment: It's actually less saving them and more assessing the damage. Ag Center expects nobody but Rangers, and got screwed from the inside, while Highpool expects backup from Skorpions and they're on high ground with the crane as the only viable access. I'm under the impression that even if they're defeated, they'll not totally collapse, so I thought that having 1 saved facility and 1 ruined town is better than having 1 barely saved town and 1 completely destroyed facility

Comment: @Raestloz I picked to save Highpool first aswell, and then go to AG center, my friend picked otherwise and saved AG center first then whent to Highpool. And they were totally wiped out, no one alive. Just like reaching AG when you've done Highpool, nothing remains. Skorpions never show up, because they were all slaughtered below in Highpool even when you go there first.

Comment: @Lyrion interesting, I don't see Skorpion units when I arrived in Highpool. Can you post your comment as answer? Also, adding a source (a pic or something) about the Skorpions getting wiped out in Highpool would be a bonus

Comment: @Raestloz I'm at work atm, so it is going to be a while since I can take the screenshot, it is also hearsay (from a friend) so I don't know if it actually is like that. But you can see the Skorpions for yourself, if you go to highpool (the city part) then near the statue to get a skillpoint is a sewer access, if you head down there you can see all the skorpions slaughtered.

Comment: @Lyrion ah! I've never been there before, I'll take a look when I got home

Comment: I wonder what will happen if you deal with the Wreckers in Highpool, but instead of continuing with fixing the pump, you go to Ag Center to help them. Anyone ever tried that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since [you cannot save *both* Highpool and Ag Center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/185415/can-you-save-both-highpool-and-the-ag-center) at least one of them will be destroyed. Which one you save is up to you and is supposed to be a tough moral choice, but also about which additional character you'd like to have (Rose in Ag Center, Vulture's Cry in Highpool or none).

You can, however, let both get destroyed. I'm not sure about the conditions, whether you simply have to wait a long time (in my experience, time passing rarely has any influence on the quests) or whether you have to visit both places and then leave.

Answer (score 2):

You can only save one of them, I personally saved highpool as I preferred the npc you get there.

As someone mentioned in the comments, you can find the scorpions in highpool and the reason why they didn't respond in the same location.

From what I have heard if you take too long in going to either location then they will both fall, but I think that takes a fair while.